the more the person is likely to ~ vs. the more likely the person is to ~
I've always read and written like 'the more likely ~', but the text says otherwise. Are two options both grammatically correct?

Internalization depends on supports for autonomy. Contexts that use
controlling strategies such as salient rewards and punishments or
evaluative, selfesteem-hooking pressures are least likely to lead
people to value activities as their own. This is not to say that
controls don’t work to produce behavior ― decades of operant
psychology prove that they can. It is rather that the more salient the
external control over a person’s behavior, the more the person is
likely to be merely externally regulated or introjected in his or her
actions. Consequently, the person does not develop a value or
investment in the behaviors, but instead remains dependent on external
controls. Thus, parents who reward, force, or cajole their child to do
homework are more likely to have a child who does so only when
rewarded, cajoled, or forced. The salience of external controls
undermines the acquisition of self-responsibility. Alternatively,
parents who supply reasons, show an emotional understanding of
difficulties overcoming problems, and use a minimum of external
incentives are more likely to cultivate a sense of willingness and
value for work in their child.

Positive Psychology in Practice
edited by P. Alex Linley, Stephen Joseph

Here's a relevant usage chart for the same construction, but comparing the more likely I am (OP's preferred version) and the more I am likely ("likely" moved to after subject+verb).

As you can see, the version with "likely" immediately after "more" wasn't always the most common. Both sequences mean exactly the same, though. Which to use is just a stylistic preference that has changed over time.
